# Filter array of objects by another array of objects key value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to filter an array if another array of objects has a key value null

Example

```
const columns = [
 {
   label: "First Name",
   field: "name"      ### this is the object key in data array
 },
 {
   label: "Price",
   field: "price"     ### this is the object key in data array
 }
];

const data = [
 {
  name: "User",
  price: null
 },
 {
  name: "User2",
  price: null
 }
];
```

**How I want the result to look like after filter**

```
const columns = [
 {
  label: "First name",
  field: "name"
 }
];
```

If you can see the object `{label: "Price", field: "price" }` has been removed because the `price` key from data objects are `null`

**What I've tried to do**

```
columns.filter(column =>
  data.find(row => row[column.field] != null
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create set/list from data which has valid keys. Then use this to filter the `columns`

```js
const columns = [
  {
    label: "First Name",
    field: "name",
  },
  {
    label: "Price",
    field: "price",
  },
];

const data = [
  {
    name: "User",
    price: null,
  },
  {
    name: "User2",
    price: null,
  },
];

const set = new Set(
  data
    .flatMap((obj) => Object.entries(obj).filter(([, v]) => v))
    .map(([key]) => key)
);

const output = columns.filter(({ field }) => set.has(field));

console.log(output)
```

Update:
Alternatively, using `forEach` and without `flatMap`.

```js
const columns = [
  {
    label: "First Name",
    field: "name",
  },
  {
    label: "Price",
    field: "price",
  },
];

const data = [
  {
    name: "User",
    price: null,
  },
  {
    name: "User2",
    price: null,
  },
];

const set = new Set();
data.forEach((obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([, v]) => v)
    .forEach(([key]) => set.add(key))
);

const output = columns.filter(({ field }) => set.has(field));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I have a problem with flapMap on old browsers. can you help me with another way to write that filter? using reducer or something?

Comment: @xflorin94, Updated the answer with alternate method. Hope this helps.